# UWP C# .Net Socket Server without CheckNetIsolation.exe LoopbackExempt

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, uwp, serversocket

I was recreating Microsoft's .Net examples for asynchronous server/client:

Asynchronous Client Socket Example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-client-socket-example

Asynchronous Server Socket Example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example

**Took me some time to figure out that I was missing to explicitly grant inbound localhost connection capabilities for the server (uwp needs that apparently) by using.
CheckNetIsolation.exe LoopbackExempt -is -n='AppContainer or Package Family' 
also see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/loopback**

Now it's working but it's not a very pretty or user-friendly solution. Is there a way to get rid of the cmd/CheckNetIsolation.exe way when the app is in deployable state later on?

Comment: The MSDN examples should work without doing anything else provided the server endpoint is configured properly.  the issue is with these two lines of code :         IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());  
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];  If you have both IPV4 and IPV6 endpoints the IPV4 is index 1 (not zero).  It is better just to use IP address Any on the server : IPAddress address = IPAddress.Any;

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, there is currently no way to cancel the local network loopback of a UWP application directly, and it can only be manually released after the application is deployed.